# How to debug Laravel API request from mobile client?

Tags: php, laravel, api, phpstorm, xdebug

I am now developing mobile app that integrated with web service.
Web service is now developing on Laravel framework.

The problem was that when I tried to debug request on Laravel project from mobile app, I couldn't handle it.

I am using PhpStorm as IDE for developing web service. For debug I've made a new Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP HTTP Request" type for this API request and executed debug.

When I get debug point, it shows:

```
"*{"error":"token_not_provided"}*"
```

Maybe I used middleware jwt.auth so if I tried to debug it, it needed token.

How can I handle this problem so I can debug api rest request from mobile app?

I use Xdebug for php debugging.

Hope to get response soon from professional developers.

Comment: What you have tried in code yet ?

Comment: I think you use post http request, and every post http request must validate csrf token

Comment: Hello, @AbdulkareemMohammed, how can I edit to validate csrf token in PHP HTTP Request in phpstorm?

Comment: you have to set your url in `$except` array in the `App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken` Class

Comment: why would api routes have the verifycsrftoken middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set your url in $except array in the App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken Class

Answer (score 1):

You're high likely missing the CSRF token.

This check can be disabled in by removing `'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` in `app/Http/Kernel.php.`

Comment: hello. thank your response. @user3601546.
can you notice me how can I edit for PHP HTTP Request in this situation?